# WSO EI6-How to write a response from a DSS to a CSV file

Tags: csv, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have created a data service GetDepartmentData service as below:

```
   <data enableBatchRequests="true" name="GetDepartmentDataService" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="LocalXEDS">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">LocalXEDB</property>
   </config>
   <query id="GetDeptQuery" useConfig="LocalXEDS">
      <sql>select dept_id,name,location from dept&#xd;where dept_id=?</sql>
      <result element="Departments" rowName="Department">
         <element column="dept_id" name="dept_id" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="name" name="name" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="location" name="location" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="dept_id" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="GetDepartment_Operation">
      <description>  Returns the departments for the given department id.                                                                      &#xd;                                    </description>
      <call-query href="GetDeptQuery">
         <with-param name="dept_id" query-param="dept_id"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

I have created a WSDl Endpoint "**MyEP**" for the data service and I have created ESB to invoke this data service and i wand to write the response in CSV file. Below is the code for same:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <dat:GetDepartment_Operation xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <dat:dept_id>$1</dat:dept_id>
                    </dat:GetDepartment_Operation>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/dat:GetDepartment_Operation/dat:dept_id" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="myEP"/>
            </call>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="file:///C:/Shilpa/sourcecode/FileConnector/Inbound?transport.vfs.Append=true"/>
            <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="order.csv"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value=""/>

            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/DBReadWritePSconfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/DBReadWritePSconfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/DBReadWritePSconfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="CSV"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/Shilpa/sourcecode/FileConnector/Inbound/order.csv"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
```

I am getting the below log message and error:

```
     WARN - XMLInputReader Element name not found : axis2ns5:Departments
[2017-03-08 21:00:36,240] [] ERROR - DataMapperMediator DataMapper mediator : mapping failed
Input type is incorrect or Invalid element found in the message payload : axis2ns5:Departments
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the datamapper  mediator you must change the payload so that it only contains the Department node. You can use the enrich mediator as follows.

```
...
<enrich>
            <source xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
                    clone="true"
                    xpath="$body//p:Departments/*[1]"/>
            <target type="body"/>
         </enrich>
<datamapper config="gov:datamapper/DBReadWritePSconfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/DBReadWritePSconfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/DBReadWritePSconfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="CSV"/>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ernesto... i tried Enrich mediator but it is still gicing the same error for Department now.                                                                                                ERROR - DataMapperMediator DataMapper mediator : mapping failed
Input type is incorrect or Invalid element found in the message payload : axis2ns5:Department

Comment: In this case I will need you to show me your datamapping configuration to reproduce the scenario in my environment.

Comment: here is my data mapping configuration in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
map_S_Envelope_S_root = function(){ 
var outputroot={};

var count_i_Department = 0;
outputroot =  {};
outputroot.Departments =  {};
outputroot.Departments.Department =  {};

for(i_Department in inputsoapenv_Envelope.soapenv_Body.Departments.Department){
outputroot.Departments.Department.dept_id = inputsoapenv_Envelope.soapenv_Body.Departments.Department[i_Department].dept_id;
outputroot.Departments.Department.name = inputsoapenv_Envelope.soapenv_Body.Departments.Department[i_Department].name;
outputroot.Departments.Department.location = inputsoapenv_Envelope.soapenv_Body.Departments.Department[i_Department].location;

count_i_Department++;
}
return outputroot;
};
```

Comment: in my case it is map_S_Department_S_Departments = function(){ 
var outputDepartments={};

outputDepartments =  {};
outputDepartments.Department =  {};
outputDepartments.Department.dept_id = inputDepartment.dept_id;
outputDepartments.Department.name = inputDepartment.name;
outputDepartments.Department.location = inputDepartment.location;
return outputDepartments;
};

Comment: Thanks...can you please share the input and output files you used for data mapper.

Answer (score 0):

My input file example(xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Department>
      <dept_id>1</dept_id>
      <name>dep1</name>
      <location>loc1</location>
   </Department>
```

My output file example (csv)

id_dept,name,location
1,dep1,loc1

My InputSchema

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://wso2.org/json-schema/wso2-data-mapper-v5.0.0/schema#",
  "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org",
  "title" : "Department",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "dept_id" : {
      "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/dept_id",
      "type" : "number"
    },
    "name" : {
      "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/name",
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "location" : {
      "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/location",
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

My OutputSchema

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://wso2.org/json-schema/wso2-data-mapper-v5.0.0/schema#",
  "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org",
  "title" : "Departments",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "Department" : {
      "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/Department",
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "dept_id" : {
          "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/Department/dept_id",
          "type" : "number"
        },
        "name" : {
          "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/Department/name",
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "location" : {
          "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/Department/location",
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "namespaces" : [ {
    "prefix" : "axis2ns4",
    "url" : "http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: thanks Ernesto, it is working now. But it works only for one record, if multiple records are fetched it writes only the last record in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Its working!!

@ Ernesto Thank you so much for your help..
i changed my dmc as below and it is working absolutely fine..

```
map_S_Departments_S_Departments = function(){ 
var outputDepartments={};

var count_i_Department = 0;
outputDepartments =  {};
outputDepartments.Department =  [];

for(i_Department in inputDepartments.Department){
outputDepartments.Department[count_i_Department] =  {};
outputDepartments.Department[count_i_Department].dept_id = inputDepartments.Department[i_Department].dept_id;
outputDepartments.Department[count_i_Department].name = inputDepartments.Department[i_Department].name;
outputDepartments.Department[count_i_Department].location = inputDepartments.Department[i_Department].location;

count_i_Department++;
}
return outputDepartments;
};
```

output:

```
110.0,PRODUCTION SUPPORT,MONTEREY, CA
110.0,DOCUMENTATION,WEXFORD, PA
110.0,ABC,wer
```